# Side menu in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, menu

I'm trying to make a side menu but it's not perfect. Take a look:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UHVnj/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="content-button">
    <div id="open-menu">Click</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <nav id="side-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("#open-menu").click(function() {
        var $cache = $("#side-menu");
      if($cache.is(":visible"))
      {
        $cache.hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, 250);
      }
      else
      {
        $cache.show("slide", {direction:"left"}, 250);
      }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#content-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#open-menu {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#side-menu {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
```

When I click on "click", the side menu appear on the left of my screen BUT :

- it appears suddenly, not with slide effect
- it appears at the top of div "content" and push all the content. I want it to appear at the left and push the entire content to the right
- it doesn't disappear when I click a second time on "click"

I hope you understood my problem.  I can't show you on JsFiddle, it doesn't work and I'm on local but I can do some screenshot if needed.

Comment: Could you post the relevant CSS?

Comment: is that really usefull ? just wait a minute, i'll write it :)

Comment: AFAIK, `.hide('slide');` [does not exist](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: #content-button {width: 100%; height: 100px;} // #open-menu {width: 50px; height: 50px;} // side-menu {position: relative; left: 0;}

I just wrote relevant CSS, nothing else

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer I think he's using the jQuery UI `hide()`: http://jqueryui.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

"slide" isn't a valid parameter to show/hide.

Instead, you can use animations.

```
$(function() {
  $("#open-menu").click(function() {
    var $cache = $("#side-menu");
    if($cache.position().left === 0)
    {
      $cache.animate({
        left: -300
      }).then(function(){
        $cache.hide();
      });
    }
    else
    {
      $cache.show();
      $cache.animate({
        left: 0
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Make sure your menu is positioned relatively.

```
#side-menu {
  position: relative;
  /* left: -300px */ /* uncomment to default hidden */
}
```

### [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/rJxgd)

Comment: Strange, i tried with your code and no slide effect... 

I have only this in the header : <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> and i call the code for menu just before </body> with this <script src="../js/side-menu.js"></script>

Maybe something is missing ?

Comment: Hi ! :). Sorry for not responding sooner but i was buzzy. So, i tried your code, it's working, when i click on my button, the menu is coming from the left with slide effect so THANKS ! But (yeah, there is a "but"), as always, it's coming from the left and push my img to the bottom of my page instead of coming over or pushing to the right :(. My img take 100% of the width

Comment: Ah, okay.  If you want the image to slide to the right (it'll be partially off screen), you can change `$cache` to `$("#side-menu,#my-big-img")`.  If you want the image to resize, you'll have to do some math by taking the final right edge of the side bar (left+width) and subtract that from the page width.

Comment: Hi :). I tried the position : absolute before you answered me and it's working perfectly ! Thanks again ;). Now can i change the speed of the transition ? It's pretty slow

Comment: I tried this but nothing has changed : {
         $cache.animate({
           left: -365
         }, 500, 'linear').then(function(){
           $cache.hide();
         }, 500, 'linear');
       }

Comment: The second parameter to `animate` is the speed.  Try 100 or 200 for very fast or fast.

Comment: I had to do some tests, read some tuto, etc... and i found it ! It's ok now, perfect, thanks again FakeRainBrigand ;)